# Update video with YOUTUBE google-api-php-client

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, google-api-php-client

I'm trying update the video metadata with Youtube API. The API which I'm using is google-api-php-client.
That API works perfectly in upload and delete processes, but when I want update the video info I don't know what parameters I have to use.

This is the code:

```
try
        {

            // Build the Needed Video Information
            $snippet = new Google_VideoSnippet();
            $snippet->setTitle($_POST['videoTitle']);
            $snippet->setDescription($_POST['videoDescription']);
            $snippet->setTags(array($_POST['videoTags']));
            $snippet->setCategoryId(22);

            // Set the Video Info and Status in the Main Tag
            $video = new Google_Video();
            $video->setSnippet($snippet);

            // Send the video to the Google Youtube API
            $created_file = $youtube->videos->update('snippet', $video, array(
                WHAT PARAMETERS!!!???!!
            ));

            // Get the information of the uploaded video
            print_r($createdFile);
        }
        catch (Exception $ex)
        {
            echo $ex;
        }
```

Someone knows this? ? i'd like keep using this API because all my aplication use it.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: I suppose that I have to pass the video Id somehow, but i don't know how pass it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update a video, first you need to use videos->list with id=video_id, then update the part intended, wrap all subparts till to the video itself into google objects, and send an update request. (We will work to make this simpler)

Here's an update tags sample which ultimately updates the video, you can use it.

```
/**
 * This sample adds new tags to a YouTube video by:
 *
 * 1. Retrieving the video with "youtube.videos.list" method setting the "id" parameter
 * 2. Appending new tags to Video Resource's snippet.tags[] list
 * 3. Updating the video itself via youtube.videos.update API call, supplying a new video via a
 * binary upload to replace the old one.
 *
 * @author Ibrahim Ulukaya
*/

// Call set_include_path() as needed to point to your client library.
require_once 'Google_Client.php';
require_once 'contrib/Google_YouTubeService.php';
session_start();

/* You can acquire an OAuth 2 ID/secret pair from the API Access tab on the Google APIs Console
 <http://code.google.com/apis/console#access>
For more information about using OAuth2 to access Google APIs, please visit:
<https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2>
Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project. */
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'REPLACE ME';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'REPLACE ME';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
    FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);

// YouTube object used to make all Data API requests.
$youtube = new Google_YoutubeService($client);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
    die('The session state did not match.');
  }

  $client->authenticate();
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: ' . $redirect);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

// Check if access token successfully acquired
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  try{

    // REPLACE with the video ID that you want to update
    $videoId = "VIDEO_ID";

    // Create a video list request
    $listResponse = $youtube->videos->listVideos("snippet",
        array('id' => $videoId));

    $videoList = $listResponse['items'];
    if (empty($videoList)) {
      $htmlBody .= sprintf('<h3>Can\'t find a video with video id: %s</h3>', $videoId);
    } else {
      // Since a unique video id is given, it will only return 1 video.
      $video = $videoList[0];
      $videoSnippet = $video['snippet'];

      $tags = $videoSnippet['tags'];

      // $tags is null if the video didn't have any tags, so we will check for this and
      // create a new list if needed
      if (is_null($tags)) {
        $tags = array("tag1", "tag2");
      } else {
        array_push($tags, "tag1", "tag2");
      }

      // Construct the Google_Video with the updated tags, hence the snippet
      $updateVideo = new Google_Video($video);
      $updateSnippet = new Google_VideoSnippet($videoSnippet);
      $updateSnippet->setTags($tags);
      $updateVideo -> setSnippet($updateSnippet);

      // Create a video update request
      $updateResponse = $youtube->videos->update("snippet", $updateVideo);

      $responseTags = $updateResponse['snippet']['tags'];


    $htmlBody .= "<h3>Video Updated</h3><ul>";
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>Tags "%s" and "%s" added for video %s (%s) </li>',
        array_pop($responseTags), array_pop($responseTags),
        $videoId, $updateResponse['snippet']['title']);

    $htmlBody .= '</ul>';
  }
    } catch (Google_ServiceException $e) {
      $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
          htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
    } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
      $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
          htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
    }

    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    } else {
      // If the user hasn't authorized the app, initiate the OAuth flow
      $state = mt_rand();
      $client->setState($state);
      $_SESSION['state'] = $state;

      $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
      $htmlBody = <<<END
  <h3>Authorization Required</h3>
  <p>You need to <a href="$authUrl">authorize access</a> before proceeding.<p>
END;
    }
    ?>

    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Video Updated</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <?=$htmlBody?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, Ibrahim. I did not know he had to do the "list video" step.<br>
It is strange that the method "update" does not have a id parameter, isn't it?
I'm gonna try it.

Comment: Another question if you please, Ibrahim, the Category video is updatable?

Comment: Yes, it is. Since you give the video object, it picks up id from it.